# the image of normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find an example of a homomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G,$ but $f(A)$ is not so in $H.$

I know that if $f$ was onto $f(A )$ must be normal , but otherwise i want to find an example!

Comment: Moreover, if $K$ is normal in $G$ then $f(K)$ is normal in $f(G)$.

Answer (score 4):

Take $A=G$ as a subgroup of $H$ that is not normal. Then define $f:G\rightarrow H$ by $x\mapsto x$

Notice here that $A=G$ is a normal subgroup of itself.

$f(A)=f(G)=G$ is not normal in $H$

Comment: wonderful!! thank u so much

Answer (score 2):

Let $H < G$ which is not normal, and the injection $H \to G$. Then $A = H$ is normal in $H$, but not in $G$.